# How do I pass a value from one TextBox to another TextBox in a different form?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Currently I have a `TextBox` on the first form called txtuserid and I want to pass the value of this to another `TextBox` called USERIDTextBox on a second form.

But when I try to run my code below, nothing gets passed to the `TextBox` on the second form.  So I'm just wondering how I can pass this value from one form to another form?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cmdlogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdlogin.Click
    Try
        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            cn.Close()

        End If
        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "select userid,state from registration where userid= " & _
            "'" & txtuserid.Text & "' and state='" & txtpw.Text & "'"

        Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If (dr.HasRows) Then
            While dr.Read

                ' My Problem: 
                ' This code shows the 2nd form but the USERIDTextBox value doesn't change?
                Dim obj As New Sale
                obj.USERIDTextBox.Text = txtuserid.Text
                obj.Show()
            End While
        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid username or PW")
        End If
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you explain how your question and your code block are connected? What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Is 'Sale' the name of your other form? You should add a messagebox in your error handler in case you're missing an exception.

Comment: YES SIR SALE IS MY ANOTHER FORM WHERE I WANT USER ID OF LOGIN FORM'S TXTUSERID VALUE TO SALE FORM'S TEXT BOX USERIDTEXTBOX.

Comment: a) dont use global connections. b) dispose of db objects to avoid leakage c) use parameters, dont concat SQL d) dont use empty Catch blocks.  If you have important data or logic to be shared with multiple forms, dont embed it inside one form.  Use a class which can easily contain logic and data shared and used throughout the app.

Comment: @Plutonix - You forgot e) please don't type in ALL CAPS!  :P

Comment: thanks sir for suggestions i will follow the same

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, it's not a good idea to try accessing another object/forms controls directly.  Instead, a better way to do it would be to pass the text in the 1st form's `TextBox` to a custom constructor on the 2nd form (the `Sale` one).  Then the constructor on the 2nd form will be responsible for setting the value of the `TextBox` .

Here is an example of one way you could do this:

**Sale.vb**

```
Public Class Sale

    Dim secondFormInputText As String

    Public Sub New(inputTextFromFirstForm As String)
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Set the class variable to whatever text string was passed to this form
    secondFormInputText = inputTextFromFirstForm
    End Sub

    Private Sub Sale_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Set the textbox text using this class variable
    USERIDTextBox.Text = secondFormInputText
   End Sub

End Class
```

**Login.vb**

```
Private Sub cmdLoginExample_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdLogin.Click
    Dim obj As New Sale(txtuserid.Text)
    obj.Show()
End Sub
```

So now instead of setting the `Sale` form's `TextBox` directly, you can pass the text on the 1st form to the constructor of the 2nd form.  The constructor can then save the text it received to a class variable that the rest of the 2nd form can use.

One of the main benefits of this, is that if in the future you change your `TextBox` to a `RichTextBox` or possibly another control that might not even have a `Text` property, you won't have to go updating every single piece of code that tries to set the textbox value directly.

Instead you can change the `TextBox` to some other control, update the `Sales` form once with whatever changes you need to work with the new control, and none of the code on the other forms should need to be changed.

**Edit:**

Even though this question was specifically about how to pass a textbox value from one form to another form,  you may also like to read the comments under your question.  In particular, Plutonix had some very helpful advice on how you can improve your database code which might be of use to you.